# How can I specify console type internalConsole in launch.json when using request: attach?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the below code, you can specify VS Code to output to the debug console:

```json
"configurations": [
       {
         "type": "java",
         "name": "CodeLens (Launch) - App",
         "request": "launch",
         "mainClass": "com.test.maven.App",
         "console": "internalConsole",
         "projectName": "my.app"
       }
     ]
```

I can't seem to find a way to make the attach config do the same, is this possible?

```
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach to Java Functions",
      "type": "java",
      "request": "attach",
      "hostName": "128.0.0.1",
      "port": 5000,
      "preLaunchTask": "func: host start",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
    }
  ]
```

I tried rewriting the attach as a launch, but could not get it to work. I also tried adapting the attach method to have a console parameter but the code was not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you can't do this is by design (see also the [extension's package.json](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/blob/main/package.json)'s `"debuggers"` field). And it's pretty logical: If you're attaching to something, that means you started running it *somewhere already*- probably via a console (Ex. a shell in VS Code's integrated terminal).